# Wildfly application user expiry

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

My wildfly application user suddenly did not work anymore and I had to reset the password. Does wildfly have some automated password expiry after a set length of time? How can I find out what happened to the user ID that my application could not login anymore? I'm on wildfly 10.

Comment: Which user?  A user added with `add-user.sh`?  Or an application specific user?  Wildfly by default doesn't have any sort of expiration for users.

Comment: Think it is an application specific user. Not sure if it's been created using add-user.sh but it's used by another application to send some data to wildfly.